# Aliasing regular array with vector intrinsics in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm playing around with the vector instrinsics in GCC, particularly for AVX, and I'm tempted to write something like this to do a vector multiply between two arrays:

```
#include <unistd.h>

void __attribute__((target("avx"))) vmul(float* __restrict__ cc, const float* __restrict__ aa, const float* __restrict__ bb, ssize_t size) {
    const ssize_t VECSIZE=8;
    typedef float vfloat __attribute__((vector_size(sizeof(float)*VECSIZE)));

    // duff's device, process any remainder up front
    ssize_t rem = size % VECSIZE;
    switch (rem) {
        case 7: cc[6] = aa[6]*bb[6]; /* FALLTHRU */
        case 6: cc[5] = aa[5]*bb[5]; /* FALLTHRU */
        case 5: cc[4] = aa[4]*bb[4]; /* FALLTHRU */
        case 4: cc[3] = aa[3]*bb[3]; /* FALLTHRU */
        case 3: cc[2] = aa[2]*bb[2]; /* FALLTHRU */
        case 2: cc[1] = aa[1]*bb[1]; /* FALLTHRU */
        case 1: cc[0] = aa[0]*bb[0]; /* FALLTHRU */
        case 0: break;
    }
    size -= rem;

    // process rest of array
    const vfloat *va = (const vfloat*)(aa+rem);
    const vfloat *vb = (const vfloat*)(bb+rem);
    vfloat *vc = (vfloat*)(cc+rem);

    for (ssize_t ii=0; ii < size; ii++) {
        vc[ii] = va[ii]*vb[ii];
    }    
}

int main() {
}
```

The problem is the pointer-aliasing required to get data into the vector type.  GCC happily lets you do it (no warning with -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic), but then assumes the underlying memory alignment is appropriate.  So it generates vmovaps instructions in the inner loop:

```
   0x0000000000400660 <+176>:   vmovaps (%rsi,%rax,1),%ymm0
   0x0000000000400665 <+181>:   vmulps (%rdx,%rax,1),%ymm0,%ymm0
   0x000000000040066a <+186>:   vmovaps %ymm0,(%rdi,%rax,1)
   0x000000000040066f <+191>:   add    $0x20,%rax
   0x0000000000400673 <+195>:   cmp    %r8,%rax
   0x0000000000400676 <+198>:   jne    0x400660 <_Z4vmulPfPKfS1_l+176>
```

Which is fine, until you pass in some non-aligned memory (or a size not a multiple of 8 in my case), and then it happily segfaults your program trying to load unaligned memory with an aligned instruction.

Is there a proper way to do this with the vector extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [reduce the alignment](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#index-aligned-variable-attribute) like this:

```
typedef float vfloat __attribute__((vector_size(sizeof(float)*VECSIZE),
    aligned(4)));
```

With that change, I get `vmovups` instructions.

Comment: Sure enough, that seems to do it.  I think that's what I need!